# Unexpected behaviour when modify an array with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want save a original array and modify the copy using a form (in a children vue component). But when the copy is modified, the origin is modified too.

I have tried:

```
this.updatedDatas = [...this.initialList]
this.updatedDatas = this.initialList.map((x)=> x)
this.updatedDatas = Array.from(this.initialList)
```

Parent script:

```
this.initialList = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Isa'}]
this.updatedDatas = [...this.initialList]
```

Parent template:

```
<form-child :item="updatedDatas[1]" />
```

Child template:

```
<textarea v-model="item.name"></textarea>
```

Child script:

```
this.$emit('updated', this.item)
```

Comment: I continue having the problem with a nested object. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do a deep copy of your array, otherwise you're just ending up with two arrays, that have the same object references. A deep copy will re-create the internals of the objects and arrays within.

You can use a package line lodash or build your own.

An external library will give you "infinite" depth, but this will give you 2 levels which may be enough for you.

```js
this.updatedDatas = this.initialList.map(i => ({...i});
```

---

additional resources for deep copying

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone

http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=363

Comment: can also use `this.updatedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialList))`

Comment: Yes, though I don't like recommending `JSON.stringify` because it may lead to errors like `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. The `clone` libraries tend to handle that better.